# How can I group geo-points to make groups on maps (using clustering method )

Tags: python, google-maps, k-means

I am developing a demo to show areas where I buy my products most. I am looking for a way to cluster a map using K-Means. In every lat/long, we have number of items that has been bought in this area. So we wanna group points based on the number of items and show the most successful areas.

I have a large data set (800 mb), the data stored this way on

```
> lat      log        n_items 
> 
> 36.3312 -94.1334    4
> 36.6828 -121.791    4
> 37.2307 -121.96     8
> 37.3857 -122.026    0
> 37.3857 -122.026    9
> 37.3857 -122.026    6
> 37.3895 -97.644     5 
> 37.3992 -122.139    7 
> 37.3992 -122.139    8
> 37.402  -122.078    12
> 37.402  -122.078    7
> 37.402  -122.078    8
> 37.402  -122.078    6
> 37.402  -122.078    5
> 37.48   -122.144    4
> 37.48   -122.144    3
> 37.55   126.967     8
```

However, I'm looking for a method to group points based on geographical proximity where I am buying most, to show it on map. Any ideas how can make this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [markerClustererPlus](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclustererplus/docs/reference.html) with Google Maps API v3. You return json (lat and lng) and load the map, and then apply markerClusterePlus.

This lib has many attributes and method that you can group based in distance, quantity, zoom, etc.

Comment: This is not the best solution in my case. However, I have a very large file, calling Google maps API every-time will take a very long time. I need to process that locally and plot data then export image.

Comment: I think you can export json object with all data and call google maps just one time.